# Creating a table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need to create a table from an array recieved with an ajax call. I am creating a 4 column table and currently using...which works but looks awful and wrong. Is there a cleaner, easier to read way to write this?

```
$("div#ColorChart").append('<tr class="colorRow"><td class="colorIDCell" style="border:thin solid;width:100px">#'+val[0]+'</td><td class="symbolCell" style="border:thin solid;width:20px;text-align:center"><img src="images/symbols/'+val[2]+'.png" width="22" height="22" alt="#'+val[2]+'"/></td><td class="colorRGBCell" style="border:thin solid;width:20px" bgcolor="#'+val[1]+'">&nbsp;</td><td class="colorNameCell">'+i+'</td></tr>'+"\n");
```

Comment: you can create a string and add readable lines with `string += "another html line"`, then just append the string `.append(string)`

Comment: This is probably what I will do. Remove the styling and make a string then append it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me, but I suggest you use a separate css file to style your elements.

And also, when I add html with jquery I do something like this:

```
$("div#ColorChart").append(
'<tr class="colorRow">' +
    '<td class="colorIDCell" style="border:thin solid;width:100px">#'+val[0]+'</td>' +
    '<td class="symbolCell" style="border:thin solid;width:20px;text-align:center">' +
        '<img src="images/symbols/'+val[2]+'.png" width="22" height="22" alt="#'+val[2]+'"/>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="colorRGBCell" style="border:thin solid;width:20px" bgcolor="#'+val[1]+'">&nbsp;</td>' +
    '<td class="colorNameCell">'+i+'</td>' +
'</tr>'+"\n");
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 3):

You ought to consider using something like templating with

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js
Or
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.2.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="template">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= data[0] %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= data[1] %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= data[2] %>
            </td>
        </tr>

</script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var template = _.template($("#template").html());
    $("#ColorChart").append(template({ data: ['Data 1','Data 2','Data 3'] }));
});
</script>

<table id="ColorChart">

</table>
```

That's a simple example using UnderscoreJS, but it should get you started!

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jcreamer898/PCYgj/

It's generally considered good practice to separate Html from JS as often as possible, plus it's way nicer looking...

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the inline styling, and use the classes to apply the styling instead. It is better practice, and will get rid of a lot of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [underscore.js template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)

Its awesome for what you want to do.

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
<tr class="colorRow">
<td class="colorIDCell" style="border:thin solid;width:100px">#<%= val0 %></td>
<td class="symbolCell" style="border:thin solid;width:20px;text-align:center">
<img src="images/symbols/<%= val2 %>.png" width="22" height="22" alt="#<%= val2 %>"/></td><td class="colorRGBCell" style="border:thin solid;width:20px" bgcolor="#<%= val1 %>">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="colorNameCell"><%= index %></td>
</tr>
</script>

var template = _.template($("#template").text());
//loop around you array
var html = template({'val0': val[0], 'val1': val[1], 'val2': val[2], 'index' : i});
$("div#ColorChart").append(html);
```

Also, don't use inline styling. Makes your code cleaner